# VS2010 will not display project properties ("underlying RCW")?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rcw, comobject, project-properties

Only sometimes (I haven't yet noticed a pattern), VS2010 shows the following error (where I'd expect the body of the property page to be) when I right-click on a project (various types of projects) and select "Properties":

[image: An error occurred trying to load the page. COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.]

I can typically view the project pages after restarting VS2010.  I'm using the RTM version.

What can cause this error?

Comment: The problem for me is intermittent.  Sometimes it goes away after restarting the IDE.  It typically will go away after rebooting the workstation.

Answer (score 4):

LepardUK. I had the same issue and finally found out what had gone wrong. It's misbehaving addin - TestDriven.NET. But things could be different for you. But anyway, it's addins. The process to find this is that you Goto "Tools -> Options" dialog. Goto "Environment -> Add-ins/Macros Security" node. Uncheck "Allow add-in components to load". And then restart VS 2010 to see if the issue goes away. If it does, then it must be an addin in those folders specified. And next step is to enable addins to load, and remove the directories in the list one by one to identity which addin caused the issue. And at last, disable or simply remove/uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Productivity Power Tools extension or StyleCop, don't remember which one. Update fixed it.

Comment: Productivity power tools was my problem - Many thanks for this